# Add your own app message/call action in native phonebook app

Tags: android, voip, phonebook

I want to add custom action to Android native phonebook app, to call/message contact via my custom VoIP app (Viber and WhatsApp have this implemented).

For example, on the screenshot provided, it is Viber's free call and free message options.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks.